# Solaris CC 12.4 compiler bug?

Tags: c++, solaris

I can use array pointers as iterators in `for_each` but when I try to do the same using `distance`, the Solaris 12.4 compiler complains about not finding a match.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::hex;

struct Bob {
   char q[16];
};

Bob stuff[16];

void DoBob(Bob& bob) {
   cout << "BOB! " << hex << &bob << endl;
}


int main() {
//   int ret = std::distance(&stuff[0], &stuff[3]);
   // The line above causes the Solaris C++ compiler to complain:
   //"main.cc", line 22: Error: Could not find a match for std::distance<_ForwardIterator, _Distance>(Bob*, Bob*) needed in main().

   std::for_each(&stuff[0], &stuff[3], DoBob);
   return 0;
}
```

I tend not to like to blame the compiler. Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem with the Solaris compiler?

Comment: Looks like a compiler/library bug. Lemme check.

Comment: I agree at first glance

Comment: Compiles fine with g++ 4.8.2 and Visual C++ 19.00, with uncommented call of `std::distance`. Try to reduce the code to the **bare minimum**, then post a bug report (if possible).

Comment: Googling it I found: "As explained in the compiler docs, the default C++ standard library, libCstd, lacks support for some standard features. One of the missing features is the distance function that takes two parameters. If you are using Forte Developer 7 (C++ 5.4) or later, you have the option of using the STLport version of the standard library instead. It provides a complete implementation of the standard library.  To use STLport, add the option"

Comment: `std::distance<_ForwardIterator, _Distance>` looks suspect as the standard 24.3 has `template <class InputIterator>
typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
distance(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);`

Comment: ... "add the option -library=stlport4 to every CC command line.  The STLport library is not compatible with libCstd. The entire program, including any shared libraries that are linked, must use either libCstd or libstlport  exclusively. You cannot use both."

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf -- Consider making your comments an answer to make this apparently unanswered question answered. As an aside, this is one weird "feature".